# How to implement a signature with Signature Pad in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a query, I want to implement Signature Pad in an ASP.NET MVC project, the idea is that when signing the form an image is saved and the url is saved in a table column, but I can't get it to work.

The program shows me the canvas without problems, and lets me clean and even download the signature file, but I can't send it to the database as a url and save the image in the "/firmas/" folder of the "wwwroot", I have not modified the Signature-pad.js file, i tried but i cant implement the signature.
I appreciate any advice or help to implement it.

*Firma.cshtml*

```
<body>
    <div class="w3-container">
        <form asp-action="Firma">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="IdOt" />

            <div id="signature-pad" class="m-signature-pad">
                <div class="m-signature-pad--body">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               
                <label asp-for="RecibiC" class="control-label">Recibí Conforme: </label>
                    <select class="form-control" asp-for="RecibiC">
                        <option value="">Seleccione una Opción</option>
                    <option value="true">Recibí conforme trabajos solicitados</option>
                        <option value="false">No recibí conforme trabajos solicitados</option>
                    </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="RecibiC" class="text-danger"></span>
                    
            </div>



            <button type="submit" id="accept" class="btn btn-info btn-icon-split">
                    <span class="icon text-white-50">
                        <i class="fas fa-signature"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Firmar</span>
                </button>
            <input type="hidden" id="SignatureDataUrl" asp-for="Firma">
        
        </form>

        <button onclick="signaturePad.clear();" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon-split">
                <span class="icon text-white-50">
                    <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="text">Limpiar</span>
            </button>
        

        
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon-split">
                <span class="icon text-white-50">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="text">Volver</span>
            </a>
        



    </div>

    <script src="~/firma/signature_pad.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad"),
            canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas"),
            signaturePad;

        /**
        *  Behandlung der Größenänderung der Unterschriftenfelds
        */
        function resizeCanvas() {
            var oldContent = signaturePad.toData();
            var ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
            canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
            canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
            canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
            signaturePad.clear();
            signaturePad.fromData(oldContent);
        }


        /**
        *  Speichern des Inhaltes als Bild
        */
        function download(filename) {
            var blob = dataURLToBlob(signaturePad.toDataURL());
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;

            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();

            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }

        /**
        * DataURL in Binär umwandeln
        */
        function dataURLToBlob(dataURL) {
            // Code von https://github.com/ebidel/filer.js
            var parts = dataURL.split(';base64,');
            var contentType = parts[0].split(":")[1];
            var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
            var rawLength = raw.length;
            var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

            for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
                uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
        }

        /**
        * Behanlung beim Absenden, damit der Inhalt des Canvas
        * übermittelt werden kann, wird dieser als DataURL dem
        * versteckten Feld zugewiesen
        */
        function submitForm() {
            //Unterschrift in verstecktes Feld übernehmen
            document.getElementById('signature').value = signaturePad.toDataURL();
        }


        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
        signaturePad.minWidth = 1; //minimale Breite des Stiftes
        signaturePad.maxWidth = 5; //maximale Breite des Stiftes
        signaturePad.penColor = "#000000"; //Stiftfarbe
        signaturePad.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"; //Hintergrundfarbe

        window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
        resizeCanvas();

    </script>
```

*AdminController.cs*

```
public async Task\<IActionResult\> Firma(int? id)
{
if (id == null)
{
return NotFound();
}

        var ordentrabajo = await _context.OrdenTrabajo.FindAsync(id);
        if (ordentrabajo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        FirmaDTO firmaDTO = new FirmaDTO();
        firmaDTO.IdOt = ordentrabajo.IdOt;
        firmaDTO.FkCategoria = ordentrabajo.FkCategoria;
        firmaDTO.FkComuna = ordentrabajo.FkComuna;
        firmaDTO.FkEmpresa = ordentrabajo.FkEmpresa;
        firmaDTO.FkUsuario = ordentrabajo.FkUsuario;
        firmaDTO.Firma = ordentrabajo.Firma;
        firmaDTO.Firmado = ordentrabajo.Firmado;
    
    
        ViewData["FkCategoria"] = new SelectList(_context.Categoria, "IdCategoria", "NombreCategoria", ordentrabajo.FkCategoria);
        ViewData["FkEmpresa"] = new SelectList(_context.Empresa, "IdEmpresa", "NombreEmpresa");
        return View(firmaDTO);
    }
    
    // POST: Comunas/Edit/5
    
    [HttpPost]
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Firma(FirmaDTO firmaDTO, string base64png)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            OrdenTrabajo ot = await _context.OrdenTrabajo.FindAsync(firmaDTO.IdOt);
            if (ot == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
    
            var dataUri = base64png;//"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...";
            var encodedImage = dataUri.Split(',')[1];
            var decodedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedImage);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("firmas/" + "signature.png", decodedImage); ot.Firma = firmaDTO.Firma;
            ot.RecibiC = firmaDTO.RecibiC;
            ot.NombreResp = firmaDTO.NombreResp;
            ot.Observaciones = firmaDTO.Observaciones;
            ot.Firmado = true;
            _context.Update(ot);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Exito));
        }  

ViewData\["FkCategoria"\] = new SelectList(\_context.Categoria, "IdCategoria", "NombreCategoria", firmaDTO.FkCategoria);
ViewData\["FkEmpresa"\] = new SelectList(\_context.Empresa, "IdEmpresa", "NombreEmpresa", firmaDTO.FkEmpresa);
return View(firmaDTO);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps possibly you could try below steps in order to carry the base64 string onto the Action Method.

1. Add "**onsubmit**" event to the form and call the same "**submitForm**" function which you have already written.
2. Current "**submitForm**" function is setting the base64 value to a wrong hidden field. You could change the ID of the hidden field or correct the ID value inside function as below :-

```js
function submitForm() {
       document.getElementById('SignatureDataUrl').value =   
signaturePad.toDataURL();
}
```

3. Since the Model that is bind to the Hidden field is "**Firma**", Inside the action method, try to access the property using the DTO object like "**firmaDTO.Firma**".

Comment: Hi!,  I implemented it i but it gave me an error, in Firma.cshtml i write `@model OTBC.Dtos.FirmaDTO` and in AdminController i have an error var `SignatureDataUrl = base64png;//"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...";
                var encodedImage = SignatureDataUrl.Split(',')[1];` System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

SignatureDataUrl is null.


the idea is that the signature url is in the "Firma" column.

Thanks for your answer as well.

Comment: Since model that is bound to a hidden field in "Firma", we need to access that property from a DTO object. If that DTO class has a different property for holding the base64 url, then bind that property to a hidden field.

`<input type="hidden" id="SignatureDataUrl" asp-for="Firma">`

Hope this helps.